# GRAPH API - retrieve Posts on a fan page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, definition

I am using the Graph API in order to obtain public posts which contain the keyword passed as query parameter (the call syntax is like this :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=post&q=%22bwatcher%22&limit=50`)
```

By reading the results, I think that I only retrieve public statuses.

I wonder if it is possible to obtain some posts on a fan page or a group (considering that the fan page and the groups are public)?

**Updated edit from OP**

What I would like to know is that if there are conditions or parameters that make the publications on a page fan wall or on a group wall available by querying the graph API ? (Is there a number of fans required, a number of group members ? Are there some privacy settings which make publications unavailable thanks to the graph API ? Are there page fan categories for which publications are avalaible are others for which they are unavailable ? etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have the object id then you can just get the feed and other connections for it. It needs an access token though, so you have to authorize a user for it.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/